# src to image put by Javascript not working in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I use plugin cordova-plugin-fetch to fetch data from **URL/JSON**.

This data is correctly fetched (cors is set to true)

In the next step, I add URL to style like background.

this tags dont work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * " />
```

```
item.style.backgroundImage = `url("${resp.image}")`;
```

resp.image have correctly path, which work corretly in app open with browser.

But inbuilt images not display, added like above or like src to the image, where is the problem?

Comment: Does `item` have any width/height for the background to show? Without seeing the final rendered html it's hard to see the issue.

Comment: Sure, have correctly width and height, in browser run work normal, only in android app version images not displayed, like backgroundImage just is empty, like src to img element show icon "broken image".

Others images from root folder work corectly too.